# how to get data from redux in componentDIdMount?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In console nothing, where can be a mistake ?
Need to get this.props.about and check empty or not.

reducer.js

```
 export default function details(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case DETAILS_SUCCESS:
  return { ...state, details: action.payload, error: '' };...
```

Container.js

```
class HeaderContainer extends Component {
  render() {
      const { details } = this.props, { deTails } = this.props.HeaderAction;
      return <div><Header deTails={deTails} about={details.details} error={details.error} /></div>
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    details: state.details,
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    HeaderAction: bindActionCreators(HeaderAction, dispatch),
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HeaderContainer);
```

Component.js

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.props.about);
}
```

Comment: where is your connect () ?

Comment: Can you provide working example that can replicate the problem? Codesandbox or Stackblitz. This could make things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You won't receive updated state as in props in componentDidMount rather you can use:

---

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){  // this is UN_SAFE 

}
```

or

```
 static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) { // this is recommended
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, can you more explain how to use?

Comment: That's how global state management (`redux` ) works, you can dispatch an action in componentDidMount later you can get updated state as in props in above mentioned lifecycles.

Comment: You must connect your component with relevant reducer so reducer when updates the store, your connected component will re render

Comment: But why getDerivedStateFromProps and not componentDidUpdate? Since no local `state` is involved, the former seems to be misused.

Comment: Of course we’ll use componentDidUpdate in case getDerivedStateFromProps doesn’t return null. Without it how can we get updated state?

Comment: @SakhiMansoor The question uses Redux 'state', while getDerivedStateFromProps is intended for `this.state`, and it looks like the answer doesn't differentiate between those two. If you have specific solution in mind, consider updating the answer with how the code from OP should be fixed, this would be helpful.

Comment: @estus thank you for putting me on the right path. To my understanding, we can only get redux state upon updating, in componentWillReceiveProps or getDerivedStateFromProps? I would really like to listen if I’m doing it wrong since whole of the time. The post is also about retrieving redux updated state

Comment: @SakhiMansoor I'm not using Redux myself so I'm not up to full answer. But `connect` should map Redux state to props, shouldn't it? And updated props are available in componentDidUpdate.

Comment: exactly we don't do it this way. setState in componentDidUpdate causes an extra render. So just we return our updated in getDerivedState and then check prevProps and nextProps in ComponentDidUpdata if they are changed. This avoids extra render

Comment: @SakhiMansoor The OP didn't specify what this prop is needed for, and there's nothing in the question about `setState`. Usually you won't use `setState` with Redux. Btw, users won't get notifications without `@`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179706/discussion-between-sakhi-mansoor-and-estus).